# Does TFS Checkin Policy Support Integration With Resharper Code Quality Analysis

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, resharper, checkin-policy

We like using the ReSharper Code Quality feature at our company to help with code standards.

I was wondering if there is a way to integrate this ReSharper feature with TFS Checkin Policy
(similar to how style cop is used)?

In other words: **Could we have TFS prevent a checkin if there are some Warnings in the ReSharper Code Quality feature?**

Comment: I have the exact same question. It's easy to show the warnings and errors, but how do you enforce them if Developers can check them in?